# add on single specific product to sql query

Tags: sql

I want to add on a single product, products_id= 886 to this query:

```
SELECT p.products_id, 
       p.products_model, 
       pd.products_name, 
       p.products_price, 
       p.products_tax_class_id, 
       p.products_image, 
       s.specials_new_products_price, 
       IF(s.status, s.msrp_price, 0)    AS msrp_price, 
       IF(s.status, s.expires_date, '') AS expiry_date 
FROM   products p, 
       products_description pd, 
       products_to_categories p2c, 
       specials s 
WHERE  p.products_status = '1' 
       AND s.products_id = p.products_id 
       AND p.products_id = pd.products_id 
       AND pd.language_id = '1' 
       AND p2c.products_id = p.products_id 
       AND p2c.categories_id IN ( 23, 75, 45, 46, 
                                  47, 48 ) 
       AND s.status = '1' 
ORDER  BY s.specials_sort_order, 
          pd.products_name
```

I still want the query to keep all the products in the category Ids queried but simply add on the single product ID mentioned above. Is that possible, or do I have to great a separate query and join them somehow?

[image: results currently]

I would like to add on 1 row (1 product) that is not in the category list, it is in a different category

Comment: your question is not clear ton me  please show a proper data sampe and the expected  result

Comment: "OR( products_id = 886) " somewhere in there. Please use modern SQL syntax.  Easier to see joins.

Comment: `if()` is non-standard SQL .Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @OldProgrammer adding Or did not seem to work because the products id is not in the category list,

Comment: @scaisEdge I added an image of the query results I am getting,

Answer (score 0):

if you need  a single row add  you could use UNION

```
SELECT p.products_id, 
       p.products_model, 
       pd.products_name, 
       p.products_price, 
       p.products_tax_class_id, 
       p.products_image, 
       s.specials_new_products_price, 
       IF(s.status, s.msrp_price, 0)    AS msrp_price, 
       IF(s.status, s.expires_date, '') AS expiry_date 
FROM   products p, 
       products_description pd, 
       products_to_categories p2c, 
       specials s 
WHERE  p.products_status = '1' 
       AND s.products_id = p.products_id 
       AND p.products_id = pd.products_id 
       AND pd.language_id = '1' 
       AND p2c.products_id = p.products_id 
       AND p2c.categories_id IN ( 23, 75, 45, 46, 
                                  47, 48 ) 
       AND s.status = '1' 

UNION 

    SELECT p.products_id, 
       p.products_model, 
       pd.products_name, 
       p.products_price, 
       p.products_tax_class_id, 
       p.products_image, 
       s.specials_new_products_price, 
       IF(s.status, s.msrp_price, 0)    AS msrp_price, 
       IF(s.status, s.expires_date, '') AS expiry_date 
FROM   products p, 
       products_description pd, 
       products_to_categories p2c, 
       specials s 
WHERE  p.products_status = '1' 
       AND s.products_id = p.products_id 
       AND p.products_id = pd.products_id 
       AND pd.language_id = '1' 
       AND p2c.products_id = p.products_id 
       AND s.status = '1' 
       AND p.products_id = 'YOUR PRODUCT CODE'
ORDER  BY s.specials_sort_order, 
          pd.products_name
```